# Is there a which statement for PYTHONPATH similar to for PATH in linux?

Tags: python

I would like to know where a script like "tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint" is located when I use the handy command "python -m tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint --file_name xyz". It is somewhere in my PYTHONPATH, but it is tedious to go through every path.

Is there a similar command to "which", aimed at quickly locating python scripts that can be reached from PYTHONPATH? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access [the `__file__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) of the module. Here is an example:

```
$ python -c "import tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint as m; print(m.__file__)"
/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py
```

You can make a shell command that takes an module as an argument and returns the `__file__` attribute.

```
function pywhich() {
  python -c "import $1 as m; print(m.__file__)"
}
$ pywhich numpy
/home/jakub/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py
```

Comment: Whether you need to use `__file__` or `__path__` appears to depend on how you did the import.